# Getting I/O reader to change Screen in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

as I started my journey of learning kivy i woanted to have an NFC reader to detect NFC cards and display certain screens on whether there is a card on one or both of the 2 readers used.

My Problem now consists of the fact that i simply cant change the Screen via the check_variables function. Is there any way to access the Value of the BooleanProperty or do i have to use a callback?

If I do have to use a callback function, how do i differenciate between if a card is placed on reader 1, 2 or if cards are present on both? (I would like to have a corresponding screen that says "place a card on reader 2 " and vice versa)

**The .kv file**

```
ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager
    IdleScreen:
        id: idle        
        manager: screen_manager
    TagOn1Screen:
        name:"tagon1"
        id: tagon1
        manager: screen_manager
    TagOn2Screen:
        name: "tagon2"
        manager: screen_manager
    TagOnBothScreen:
        id: tagonboth
        manager: screen_manager
    ErrorScreen:
        id: error
        manager: screen_manager

<IdleScreen>:
    
    BoxLayout:
        
        Label:
            text:"IdleScreen"


<TagOn1Screen>:
    
    Label:
        text:"Tagon1Screen"


<TagOn2Screen>:
    
    Label:
        text:"Tagon2Screen"


<TagOnBothScreen>:
    
    Label:
        text:"tagonbothScreen"


<ErrorScreen>:
    Label:
        text:"ErrorScreen"
```

**The .py file**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7
from time import sleep
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.event import EventDispatcher
from functools import partial
from time import sleep
#import concurrent.futures
from Simple_RFID import SimpleMFRC522
import RC522_mod
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from threading import Thread


TAG_ON_1 = False
TAG_ON_2 = False
id1 = ObjectProperty(None)
id2 = ObjectProperty(None)
text1 = ObjectProperty(None)
text2 = ObjectProperty(None) 


class IdleScreen(Screen):
    
    
    
    
    def check_for_tag(reader, msg):
        global TAG_ON_1
        global TAG_ON_2
        print(msg)
        (status, TagType) = reader.READER.MFRC522_Request(reader.READER.PICC_REQIDL)
        while status != reader.READER.MI_OK:
            sleep(0.1)
            (status, TagType) = reader.READER.MFRC522_Request(reader.READER.PICC_REQIDL)
            if status == reader.READER.MI_OK:
                break
        if status == reader.READER.MI_OK:
            if msg == "1":
                TAG_ON_1=True
                id1, text1 = reader.read()
                print("Funktion hier: TAG auf 1 zu true gesetzt")
            else:
                TAG_ON_2 = True
                print("Funktion hier: TAG auf 2 zu true gesetzt")
                id2, text2 = reader.read()
            #print (f" Tag Read, id= {id} Reader = {msg}")
            pass 
   

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        reader_0 = SimpleMFRC522(0,0,15)
        reader_1 = SimpleMFRC522(1,0,22)
        t1= Thread(target=IdleScreen.check_for_tag, args=(reader_0,'1'))
        t2= Thread(target=IdleScreen.check_for_tag, args=(reader_1,"2"))
        t1.daemon=True
        t2.daemon=True
        t1.start()
        t2.start()
        print("Startup initialized")
        
    pass

class TagOn1Screen(Screen):
    pass
class TagOn2Screen(Screen):
    pass
class TagOnBothScreen(Screen):
    pass
class ErrorScreen(Screen):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file('Stylefile.kv')
class FotoboxApp(App):
    global TAG_ON_1
    global TAG_ON_2
    global id1
    global id2
    global text1
    global text2
    
    
    

    def build(self):
        '''
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(IdleScreen(name="idle"))
        sm.add_widget(TagOn1Screen(name="tagon1"))
        sm.add_widget(TagOn2Screen(name="tagon2"))
        sm.add_widget(TagOnBothScreen(name="tagonboth"))
        sm.add_widget(ErrorScreen(name="error"))
        return sm
        '''
        
        return kv
    
    def on_stop(self):
        print("Kehring & Beenden!")
        Clock.stop()
        GPIO.cleanup()
    
    def check_variables(self, *args):
        
        print("checking variables")
        print(f"Tag on 1 = {TAG_ON_1}")
        print(f"Tag on 2 = {TAG_ON_2}")
        if TAG_ON_1 == True and TAG_ON_2 == False:
            self.root.ids.screen_manager.current = self.root.ids.screen_manager.tagon1
        if TAG_ON_1 is False and TAG_ON_2:
            self.root.ids.screen_manager.current=tagon2
        if TAG_ON_1 is True and TAG_ON_2 is True:
            self.root.ids.screen_manager.current=tagonboth
        if TAG_ON_1 is False and TAG_ON_2 is False:
            print("No tag Found")
            
    Clock.schedule_interval(check_variables,1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    FotoboxApp().run()
```

Thanks alot in advance!

*EDIT*
Updated the .ky and .py file and moved check_variables in main app class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of defining `check_variables` inside `IdleScreen` class, define it in your main app. In .kv use a screen manager to manage screen and give it an id, let's say `screen_manager`. Then whenever you want to change screen just use the code `self.root.ids.screen_manager.current = "screen_name"`

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply! I succesfully moved the check_variables and it does check them as desired. But as soon as i would like to change the Screen i get multiple errors with the `self.root.ids.screen_manager.current= tagon1` for example. (used the id:tagon1 inside the .kv under the screenmanager i declared) is there any "better" way to call those ids out of the Screenmanager?

Comment: Well `tagon1` is screen_id or name? If its id then to get it use `self.root.ids.screen_manager.tagon1 ` and if its name then use `self.root.ids.screen_manager.get_screen("tagon1")`. And did you put `tagon1` inside quotes? It should be like like `self.root.ids.screen_manager.current = "tagon1"`

Comment: Dear Ankit, I tried it with both approaches but only gett errors in return. If i try to run it calling the id (`self.root.ids.screen_manager.current= self.root.ids.screen_manager.tagon1` i get the following error: `self.root.ids.screen_manager.current = self.root.ids.screen_manager.tagon1
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'root'` Thnk you very much for your patience. for better understanding of my code i updated the original questions code blocks with the changes you supposed!

Comment: No, you don't have to. Just use `self.root.ids.screen_manager.current = "tagon1"`. what error are you getting if you do this? and sorry I can't run the code so just tell me what error are you getting with this?

Comment: just tried this example and got the following error output: `File "/home/pi/Desktop/zweigleichzeitig_kivy (2).py", line 114, in check_variables
    self.root.ids.screen_manager.current = "tagon1"
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'root'`

Comment: ok so your self is a float object. Then try self.parent.root.....

Comment: Dear Ankit, initially this wasn't working as well. Due to alot of trial and error i more or less guessed it right by using the name property and `self.root.current='tagon1'`Thanks alot for your patience and knowledge!

Comment: Glad to hear that. Well `self.root` should be your app then from it we get `screen_manager` using `id`. But if you are saying that `self.root.current` is working then that means your `screen_manager` is the root in your case, not your app.